# Submit Form with AJAX PHP JQuery takes me to action page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am trying to submit this form without refreshing the page , but when i submit it takes me to action page. what is wrong with my code?
This is my form:

```
<form class="ajax" action="/../addchannel/createUser.php" method="post" >
<input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="userName"><br>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br>
<input  type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>';
```

And this is my script:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function () {
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find(['name']).each(function (index, value)) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        consol.log(response)
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Pass event as argument and use `event.preventDefault()`.

**Example**

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `return false` at the end or prevent default.

```
 $('form.ajax').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
var that = $(this),
    url = that.attr('action'),
    type = that.attr('method'),
    data = {};
   ....
  //or return false;
    
});
```

Comment: it i put event.preventDefault(); nothing happens and submit button stops working:(

Comment: did u try with return false ??

Comment: yes i used boyh event.preventDefault(); and return false. and if i add these button stops working , nothing happens .

Comment: use one .. either preventDefault or return false

Answer (score 1):

Use [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) or `return false;` to prevent form submitting

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function (e) {//Pass the event argument here
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find(['name']).each(function (index, value)) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });
   $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        consol.log(response)
    }
   });
 e.preventDefault(); 
 //OR
return false;
});
```

Comment: little help how can do something like this $( ".list #"+clickedId ).remove();

Answer (score 1):

Use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //code here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
<form method='post' action="javascript:mail();" >
<input type="text" class="input-large" id="user_name" name="name">
<input type="text" class="input-large" id="email" name="name">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
</form>

function mail()
{
var name = $("#user_name").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
$.ajax({
                type:       "POST",
                url:        "contact.php",
            data:        "name=" + name+"&customer_mail="+email,
                success:    function(html) {
            //do ur function
                }

            });


}
```

Comment: but it takes value of one input field .

Comment: but with my code , i can add any no of input field , without adding anything in my script :)

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery ajax is not preventing browser to follow Form Action page.
To achieve this, you should prevent browser to do it by simple function: [e.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

Here is you code:

```
//Pass the event argument (e)
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function (e) { 
    var that = $(this),
        url = that.attr('action'),
        type = that.attr('method'),
        data = {};

    that.find(['name']).each(function (index, value)) {
        var that = $(this),
            name = that.attr('name'),
            value = that.val();
        data[name] = value;
    });
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: type,
    data: data,
    success: function (response) {
        consol.log(response)
    }
});

//Prevent Browser to follow form action link:
e.preventDefault();

//you can use also
// return false;

});
```

Comment: if i put event.preventDefault(); nothing happens and submit button stops working:(

Comment: what is your `url` in `$.ajax` call?

Comment: from this form : <form class="ajax" action="/../addchannel/createUser.php" method="post" > 

 url = that.attr('action'),

Comment: check console. do you get responce from this ajax call?