# remove a div on success function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove a div using jquery, but its not working.

This is my html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="logout">
<form class="ajax" method="post" action="">
<div id="box_22">
<div id="box_23">
<div id="box_56">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
<script src="/../js/tt.js" type="text/javascript">
</body>
</html>
```

and my script is : how do i delete a box .

```
$(".delBtn").click(function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var clickedID = 'clickId=' + this.id;       
        jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "/addchannel/delUsr.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data:clickedID, //Form variables
        success:function(response){
            alert("#box_"+clickedID);
            $( "div #box_"+clickedID ).remove();


        },
 });
 });
```

Comment: Where's the element with class `delBtn` in that HTML? Also where are the closing tags? If that's your actual HTML it's totally invalid, and you can't guarantee any specific behaviour with it.

Answer (score 5):

Your selector is wrong.... `"div #box_"+clickedID` is searching for an element with id `"#box_"+clickedID` inside a `div` element.

In your case you can use the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) directly

**Update**: The real culprit is the variable `clickedID`, you created it as a param string.... so the selector will fail.

```
$(".delBtn").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    var clickedID = 'clickId=' + id;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
        url: "/addchannel/delUsr.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
        dataType: "text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
        data: clickedID, //Form variables
        success: function (response) {
            alert("#box_" + id);
            $("#box_" + id).remove();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The divs with IDs starting with `box_` *are* in a div in the HTML he's posted, so the selector is fine (just pointless). EDIT: Oh, wait, no closing tags... God knows how that page is supposed to look. :/

Comment: this is not working. but if i do this $( "div" ).remove(); it works only it removes every div.

Comment: closing tags are there , i hv copied DOM model from firebug so it looks like this.

Comment: @phpdeveloper yes... the real culprit is the variable `clickedID`, it was not a selector... it was a param string... see the update

Comment: @phpdeveloper Copy the actual HTML source next time, posting the DOM view from Firebug doesn't help anybody.

Comment: what is the alert displayed

Comment: @ Arun P Johny @Anthony Grist  suddenly it worked , thanks Sir.

Comment: @ Arun P : can u help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564281/submit-form-with-ajax-php-jquery-takes-me-to-action-page/19564309?noredirect=1#comment29033932_19564309

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space:

```
$( "div#box_"+clickedID ).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the 'div' in the Jquery selector

```
$( "#box_"+clickedID ).remove();
```