# My async fetch function takes me to the endpoint I POST to. I want it to refresh the page it POSTS from

Tags: javascript, php, async-await

My async fetch function is embedded on names.php and when I activate the function it takes me to the endpoint it POSTS to: change-name.php. I want to remain on the names.php page but refresh that page after the fetch function has run.

I am clicking the span below to open a text field where I add a name and click the button:

```
<span onclick="addGuestName(this)">

<button class="addPaxName btn btn-xs btn-warning">ADD</button>
```

This works perfectly fine. And updates the name but I am transported to the /change-name.php page after clicking the ADD button.

My desired response is to remain on the original page with a page refresh after the fetch function has completed.
How do I get this result.

```
async function updateGuestName(paxid,name){
paxIDbody = '{"pxid": "' + paxid + '", "name": "' + name + '"}';
  console.log("PaxID:", paxIDbody);
  try {
    const settings = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
      },
      body: paxIDbody,
    };
    const response = await fetch(
      "/change-name.php",
      settings
    );
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("DATA: ",data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR: ",error);
  }
}

function addGuestName(obj) {
  const itemClicked = obj;
  const paxid = obj.id;
  const addPaxName = itemClicked.nextElementSibling;
  const addPaxNameButton = itemClicked.nextElementSibling;
  addPaxNameButton.style.display = 'inline-block';
  var addPaxNameField = document.createElement('input');
  addPaxNameField.setAttribute('type', 'text');
  addPaxNameField.setAttribute('name', 'visitorNameSurname[]');
  addPaxNameField.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Enter Name & Surname');
  itemClicked.parentNode.insertBefore(addPaxNameField, itemClicked.nextSibling);
  addPaxNameField.setAttribute("required", "required");
  addPaxNameButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const name = addPaxNameField.value;
    updateGuestName(paxid,name);
  })
}
```

My PHP endpoint returns JSON after the DB update:

```
header('Content-type:application/json;charset=utf-8');
    $myObj=new \stdClass();
    $myObj->status = $status;
    $myObj->message = $message;
    $myJSON = json_encode($myObj);
    echo $myJSON;
```

Comment: Default button type is `submit`. Just use `type="button"`.

Comment: @bigless No ways, now why didn't I think of that! :)

Comment: @bigless Add this as your answer and I'll accept it, it has solved the mystery. Thanks!

Comment: It is [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564281/submit-form-with-ajax-php-jquery-takes-me-to-action-page). There will be question with answer similar to mine too for sure. Being you, I would delete it to make this place cleaner ;)

Comment: I get you, but that question is jQuery Ajax, not vanilla JS.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't able to find single one answer for vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

Default button type is submit. Use [onsubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onsubmit) with `event.preventDefault()` inside `onsubmit` callback. If you don't need browser's form validation, you can use more straightforward `type="button"`. For refreshing page look at  [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload).

Answer (score 1):

```
addPaxNameButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const name = addPaxNameField.value;
    updateGuestName(paxid,name);
  })
```

Comment: While this may be the solution you should explain an answer so it's not just code only.